# Adding set of <TR> onto a table from DOM via javascript and AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

I am a beginner with javascript ajax, and all this web stuff.

I have a situation, similar to what was posted (and seemingly solved) in [How to insert a a set of table rows after a row in pure JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753344/how-to-insert-a-a-set-of-table-rows-after-a-row-in-pure-js)

In my case, I have `xmlhttp.responseText` returning a set of TRs from an AJAX call. I need to add it to the end of a table on the page it is called from.

I was using `document.getElementById("posts").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText;` It worked well on all except IE, and having  read into it, I think I understand why ([read this](http://www.ericvasilik.com/2006/07/code-karma.html)).

In your code snippet

```
function appendRows(node, html){  
    var temp = document.createElement("div"); 
    var tbody = node.parentNode; 
    var nextSib = node.nextSibling; 

    temp.innerHTML = "<table><tbody>"+html; 
    var rows = temp.firstChild.firstChild.childNodes; 

    while(rows.length){ 
        tbody.insertBefore(rows[i], nextSib); 
    } 
}
```

What does node mean? I am trying to find where I can get that in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node` appears to be the TR that the other table rows will be inserted after.

Comment: Thanks Justin. Though I have nt achieved any results yet. learning by trial and error. I thought I would simplify the question, if one of the experts can point me in the right direction. I have ' xmlhttp.responseText="<tbody><tr><td> a</td><td> b</td></tr><tr><td> c</td><td> d</td></tr></tbody>";' Seems to append to existing table in all but IE using document.getElementById("posts").innerHTML+=xmlhttp.responseText; Do I need to do anything more specific? Anyone? Thx